# How can I set the path of the script as working directory in Python using Atom editor?

Tags: python

I want to set the path of the python script as the working directory. I've tried the solutions I've found other solutions, but they aren't working for me.

This solution:

```
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
dn = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))
dn
```

gives:

```
'C:\\Users\\23392\\Desktop'
```

and my script is in a folder of desktop.

This solution:

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

gives the following error:

```
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

I need to define it as a string to prevent the error. And I get the same result that the previous one:

```
'C:\\Users\\23392\\Desktop'
```

The path should be:

```
C:\Users\23392\Desktop\05_Work\test.py
```

**EDIT**

I've found a partial solution. If I open the file with right click->open with->Atom, it recognizes the path of the file. It works this way but it has to be another way to do it.

Comment: path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) should have given you correct path (full directory path where script is present).

Comment: This gives the path of python.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this version:

```
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
basename = os.path.basename(__file__)
fullpath = os.path.join(abspath + "\\" + basename)

print(fullpath)
```

Write this code into a file and then run it using Python interpreter.

If you try it from an interactive shell it will not work, __file__ is not defined in the interactive interpreter because it is meaningless there.

It is set by the import implementation, so if you use a non-standard import mechanism it might also be unset.

Comment: I've tried with this code on the power shell and it doesn't recognize __file__ as well.

Comment: On a normal windows shell it works without issues.
Can you please check it using a normal command prompt?